# Problems with making a query when using Enum in entity

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have the following in a Question entity:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Question.allApproved",
    query = "SELECT q FROM Question q WHERE q.status = 'APPROVED'")
```

and

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

// usual accessors
```

I am getting this exception:

> Exception Description: Error compiling the query
>   [Question.countApproved: `SELECT COUNT(q) FROM Question q WHERE q.status = 'APPROVED'`], line 1, column 47: invalid enum equal
>   expression, cannot compare enum value of type
>   `[myCompnay.application.Status]` with a non enum value
>   of type `[java.lang.String]`.     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:501)

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you using a custom enum? Can you update the document to show the Status enum?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I think you should use your (fully qualified) `Status` enum instead of literal value, so something like this: (assuming your `Status` enum is in `com.myexample` package)

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Question.allApproved", 
            query = "SELECT q 
                     FROM Question q 
                     WHERE q.status = com.myexample.Status.APPROVED").
```

Comment: What about a JPA2 regular @Query ? It complains with: The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression.

Comment: What `@Query` annotation are you talking about?

Comment: This `fully qualified` is more important as I thought it could be.

Comment: On a sidenote: It didn't work when the enum was an inner class of the entity. If this doesn't work for you, make sure the enum is it's own file!

Comment: @evandongen any solution if enum is inner class?

Comment: @Rajaaar, there wasn't unfortunately

Comment: ok, luckily my code is flexible enough to send list of enum when calling the repo method.
Example, 
@Query("SELECT a from <yourEnitity> a where a.Status IN (:statuses)")
myRepo.someMethodName(@Param("statuses") List<enum class> statuses)
This worked for me. 
anyway thanks for the response @evandongen

Comment: @evandongen, see this answer from another thread to deal with inner classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393602/3232174

Comment: Note that for example to work enum from query needs to be public, I had them as package private (in the same package as jpa repo) and I was getting errors.

Comment: @raja-aar see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995708/3632617

Comment: this does not seem to work in Hibernate 6.1 , I'm presented with the following error now:  org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'com.myexample.Status.APPROVED' . the enum is in its own file and also public.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) in the @NamedQuery (or @Query) annotation and then use the properties of the param object in the query.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Question.allApproved",
    query = "SELECT q FROM Question q WHERE :#{#q.status.name()} = 'APPROVED'")
```

Answer (score -3):

4 years since the initial post, there are some developments. Using spring 4 and  Hibernate 4 it's now possible to 'trick' Hibernate using a SpEL expression. For example:

The enum:

```
package com.mycompany.enums

public enum Status {
    INITIAL, PENDING, REJECTED, APPROVED, SHIPPED, DELIVERED, COMPLETE;
}
```

Here's a wrapper class called 'Filter' which we'll pass to the repository filtering method.

```
package com.mycompany.enums

public class Filter implements Serializable {

    /** The id of the filtered item */
    private Integer id;
    /** The status of the filtered item */
    private Status status;
    // more filter criteria here...

    // getters, setters, equals(), hashCode() - omitted for brevity

    /**
     * Returns the name of the status constant or null if the status is null. This is used in the repositories to filter
     * queries by the status using a the SPEL (T) expression, taking advantage of the status qualified name. For example:
     * {@code :#{T(com.mycompany.enums.Status).#filter.statusName}}
     *
     * @return the status constant name or null if the status is null
     */
    public String getStatusName() {
        return null == status ? status : status.name();
    }

 }
```

Finally, in the repository, we can now use the Filter class as the single parameter and make the query translate what appears to be a mixture of literals and SpEL expressions to a Status object:

The repository:

```
package com.mycompany.repository

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT o from Order o "
            + "WHERE o.id = COALESCE(:#{#filter.id},o.id) "
            + "AND o.status = COALESCE(:#{T(com.mycompany.enums.Status).#filter.statusName},o.status)")
    public List<Order> getFilteredOrders(@Param(value = "filter") Filter filter);
}
```

This works perfectly, but for some odd reason I haven't figured out yet, if you enable SQL debugging in Hibernate and turn on the binder logging, you'll not be able to see Hibernate binding this expression to query variables.

Comment: You don't see it among the variable bindings because the constant has already been substituted into the query string.