# How should I refer to inner enums (defined within an entity) from a JPQL query using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, jpql

I have an entity class as follows:

```
package stuff;

@Entity
class Thing {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Enumerated
    private State state;

    public enum State {
        AWESOME,
        LAME
    }
}
```

How can I select all Things with state AWESOME using JPQL and Hibernate?

```
select t from Thing t where t.state=stuff.Thing.State.AWESOME
```

...gives the error...

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'stuff.Thing.State.AWESOME'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the following idiom:

```
select t from Thing t where t.state=stuff.Thing$State.AWESOME
```

`Type$InnerType` is Java's naming convention for inner types.

When you try to use dot notation, Hibernate assumes that you're trying to access nested properties, which (properly) fails in this case.

Comment: better still use a parameter, and pass an enum value in as the parameter value ... and the query is reusable for other parameter values

Comment: @NeilStockton: Some more complex queries might only make sense in the context of a particular state. You're right that in simple cases like the example, using a parameter might be more flexible. The question was limited to syntax ;)

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? It took me hours to find out that JPQL/Hibernate expects a dollar sign for inner/nested classes. By the way, if your *entity* happens to be an inner class, you can do "select e from DataEntity$NestedSubClassEntity e"

Comment: Not documented. I had to go read Hibernate sources to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t from Thing t where t.state='AWESOME'
```

Comment: This works, but breaks type checking and refactoring for JPA-aware IDEs like IntelliJ. Better to use the type rather than a string representation, I think.

Comment: As of 5/2021, IntelliJ doesn't recognize the Syntax with $-signs for inner classes though, so it breaks refactoring either way

Comment: Pretty sure it worked several years ago when this question was posted. Sounds like someone should file a bug against IntelliJ ;)