# How to use enum in @Query as a constant

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have tried to put a full class path (com.xxxx.State.Finish) after `!=` but not helping.

```
@Query("select c from CustomOrder c where c.dealer = :roleName and 
     c.nextManager = null and c.currentState != Finish")
List<CustomOrder> findOpenOrder(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
```

Entity:

```
@Getter
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
CustomOrderEnums.State currentState;
```

Enum:

```
public enum State {
    Open, Finish
}
```

Comment: you get any exception?

Comment: `... and c.currentState = com.xxxx.CustomOrderEnums.State.Finish` works for me.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'com.xxx.CustomOrderEnums.Status.Finish'`, in IDE I could open Finish definition by pressing on that `@Query`.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I was thinking the same, but it throws `hibernate invalid path exception`

Comment: com.xxxx is just an example. You need to put there your path to the enum.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I am using a valid path...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@Query("select c from CustomOrder c where c.dealer = :roleName and 
     c.nextManager = null and c.currentState != com.xxx.FooEnum.Finish")
```

`FooEnum` has to be a top class not an inner one. If it has to be an inner class, use `'` quoted string (haven't tried it without `'`).

```
@Query("select c from CustomOrder c where c.dealer = :roleName and 
     c.nextManager = null and c.currentState != 'Finish'")
```

I have just found that instead of using `@Query` it could be simply used as:

```
List<User> findIdByRoleRoleAndProvinceType(String role, ProvinceEnum.ProvinceType provinceType);
```

and this is entity User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    Role role; // entity has a String field role;
    Province province; // entity has a ProvinceEnum.ProvinceType field type.
...
}
```

Comment: I was having the same problem, and as per your answer, moving the declared enum out of the class it was in and into its own did the trick, cheers.

I would note - that example you give with `and c.currentState != 'Finish'` is really just doing a string comparison (in the DB) - it's not using the enum value. If you changed that enum value you'd have to come back and update the query to fix it.

Comment: @PhilBrock true

Comment: For inner class enums just use `$` sign between containing class and enum name, like: `com.evil.Account$Status.LOCKED`